# Using QMK, how can I change octaves or transpositions with a knob on my keyboard?

Tags: qmk, qmk-firmware

I want to change octaves or transpositions when turning the knob on my keyboard. What could I do to get the following code to work?

```
typedef enum {
ENCODER_MODE_OCTAVE,
ENCODER_MODE_TRANSPOSE,
} encoder_mode_t;

encoder_mode_t encoder_mode = ENCODER_MODE_OCTAVE;

bool encoder_update_user(uint8_t index, bool clockwise) {
    if (layer_state_is(MIDI_BASE)) {
        if (clockwise) {
            if (encoder_mode == ENCODER_MODE_OCTAVE) {
                tap_code16(MI_OCTU);
            } else {
                tap_code16(MI_TRSU);
            }
        } else {
            if (encoder_mode == ENCODER_MODE_OCTAVE) {
                tap_code16(MI_OCTD);
            } else {
                tap_code16(MI_TRSD);
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

- I receive 'something' when turning the knob, but it's not `MI_OCTx` or `MI_TRSx`.
- The documentation specifies `tap_code16(<kc>);` so I'm thinking that I can only send `KC_x` keycodes, but I am unsure.
- Using `MI_OCTx` or `MI_TRSx`in my keymap works.
- As a last option, I could implement octave and transposition changes in `process_record_user` by adding or subtracting from the midi note values before using `midi_send_noteon`, but I am hoping for a 'simpler' solution.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. MIDI events and real keyboard events are processed separately: `OCTx` and `TRSx` are processed in [`process_midi`](https://github.com/qmk/qmk_firmware/blob/325da02e57fe7374e77b82cb00360ba45167e25c/quantum/process_keycode/process_midi.c#L75), which is part of the process that regular keymap goes through, but not part of `tap_code*`. Moreover, those OCTx/TRSx and other MIDI functions are not exposed for users to call.

I do have an idea, but haven't looked into this myself, so please take it as a grain of salt.

The goal here is to utilize those internal MIDI functions that are already in `process_midi`, and we want to be able to do this from `process_record_user` (or `pre_process_record_user`). The idea is to change the content of `*record` on the fly so the keycode becomes MI_OCTx. When it reaches `process_midi`, it'll do what MI_OCTx is supposed to do. I expect you'll need to do some `(un)register_code` to keep the queue clean.